# Как передать form в AJAX?

Tags: python, django

Уважаемые форумчане!
Как в

```
$.ajax({ 
 type: "POST", 
 url: "/polls/add_dise", //или url: $(this).attr('action'); 
 data: data,
});
```

В data добавить именно форму, чтобы во вьюхе потом обработать:

```
form=AddForm(request.POST) 
if form.is_valid(): 
      new_post.save()
```

?

Я пробовал как-то так

```
data : {{ new_dise }};
```

где new_dise - это ModelForm, переданная в шаблон из view. 
У меня на выходе какая-то ерунда получается

Answer (score 1):

Решение было простым:

```
data : $('#addis').serialize();
```

где addis - id тега  формы, которую надо отправить